# Get all input elements

Tags: dart

I have a form:

```
<form id="form">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username"><br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="password" id="password"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" disabled>
</form>
```

How to get all input elements of the form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var form = querySelector("#form");
form.querySelectorAll("input").forEach((Element el){

})
```

Answer (score 3):

```
querySelectorAll('#form input[type=text]')
```